# I want my telerik pie chart drilled down to telerik stacked bar chart

Tags: asp.net, telerik, telerik-reporting

We are using **telerik charting** demo version.

we want to know if we can drill down from **telerik pie chart** to **telerik stacked bar chart** or not. 
We don't want drill down to a specific portion of the pie. But we have scenarios where we have 5 portions of data for a group in pie chart. When we click on the pie chart, it will drill us down to each group members' stacked bar where each bar has same 5 portion of data belonging to them.

Is it possible with telerik charts ?

I am using **asp.net** web application.

Need a suggestion: which are good chart controls ? I searched lot on the internet and am confused. I want controls which don't have limitations. I don't want to not be able to drill down on pie or something like that.

Help is appreciated.

thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drilldown is achieved by initiating a (partial) postback so you can modify the control on the server: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/htmlchart/examples/drilldownchart/defaultcs.aspx.
Instead of changing field names, you can simply hide the current chart and show another one with the desired properties and series.